# How can I change a float value between -1 and 1 usig Update or StartCoroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PlayerLoop;

public class ChangeShaders : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int val;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine(EffectSliderChanger());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("Effect Slider", val);
        Mathf.Lerp(-1, 1, Time.deltaTime);
    }

    /*IEnumerator EffectSliderChanger()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("Effect Slider", 1);
    }*/
}
```

I want to change the effect value between -1 and 1 nonstop from -1 to 1 when it's getting to 1 back to -1 and so on.

I'm not sure how to do it and if to use StartCoroutine or to do it inside the Update.

Comment: On each frames ? Every x.y seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) for this

```
Material material;

// Adjust via Inspector
public float duration = 1;

private void Awake()
{
    material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
}

void Update()
{
    var currentValue = Mathf.Lerp(-1 , 1, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / duration, 1));
    material.SetFloat("Effect Slider", currentValue);
}
```

Alternatively you could also simply shift the range like

This will move between `-1` and `1` using the result of `PingPong` as the interpolation factor which moves between `0` and `1` in the given duration.

Alternatively you could also directly shift the range of `PingPong` like

```
var currentValue = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / duration, 2) - 1f;
```

Comment: Will it pingpong between -1 and 1 ?

Comment: @bendivonim now yes ;)

Comment: Working perfect. I have a question about getting the material properties automatic without giving a string should I ask a new question ?

Comment: @bendvivonim yes this would be a different question, however if this is a special shader property usually going by string is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I haven't tested it but it should work):

```
public class ChangeShaders : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float fromValue = -1f;
    private float toValue = 1f;
    private float timeStep = 0f;
    private float val = 0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("Effect Slider", val);
        val = Mathf.Lerp(fromValue, toValue, timeStep);

       timeStep += Time.deltaTime;
       // If you want the values to go back and forth faster use the line below instead
       // timeStep += 0.2f + Time.deltaTime;

       if (timeStep >= 1f) {
          float tempVal = toValue;
          toValue = fromValue;
          fromValue = tempVal;
          timeStep = 0f;
       }
    }
}
```